# Traer fecha y hora actual

Tags: sql-server

Quiero poner la fecha y la hora actual en este script

```
select convert(datetime, cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4)) + '-' 
+ cast(month(getdate()) as varchar(2)) 
+ '-' + cast(day(getdate()) as varchar(2)) + ' 12:00:00.000');
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu versión de SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Si solamente te interesa una cadena con la fecha/hora actual, puedes hacerlo así:

- **SQL Server 2012+**

  ```
  SELECT FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') hora_actual;
  ```

Lo interesante aquí es que puedes usar cualquiera de las representaciones de `FORMAT` para dar el estilo que quieras a la salida.

---

```
    --Salida:

    hora_actual
    2018-05-25 15:55:40
```

- **SQL Anterior a 2012:**

  ```
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 120) hora_actual;
  ```

  ---

  ```
  --Salida:

  hora_actual
  2018-05-25 15:55:40
  ```

**NOTA:** `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` no arroja realmente un objeto fecha, si quieres trabajar con objetoS fecha como tal debes usar `SYSDATETIME()` o bien `GETDATE()`.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') hora_actual;   -- 2012+
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), SYSDATETIME(), 120) hora_actual;       -- 2012-


SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') hora_actual;       -- 2012+
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120) hora_actual;           -- 2012-
```

Las salidas serán siempre las mismas.

Answer (score 1):

Debes de hacerlo asi

```
select 
convert(datetime, cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4))
+ '-' + cast(month(getdate()) as varchar(2)) 
+ '-' + cast(day(getdate()) as varchar(2))) + 
convert(time,getdate());
```

Comment: Gracias mil, excelente brot!!